# Elasticsearch 'match' doesn't work with Dynamic Templates

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a dynamic template based on some matching criteria but when I am using "match" attribute it's not working. More specific , I want to create a dynamic template with the standard_analyzer (already imported in settings) when field ends with _analyze.

Desired results on Mapping:

```
{
   "count": {
      "type": "integer"
   },
   "is_top": {
      "type": "boolean"
   },
   "keywords_analyze": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "std_analyzer": {
            "type": "text",
            "term_vector": "yes",
            "analyzer": "standard_analyzer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

currently mapping i am doing:

```
{
   "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
         {
            "integers": {
               "match_mapping_type": "long",
               "mapping": {
                  "type": "integer"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "strings": {
               "match_mapping_type": "string",
               "mapping": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "strings_analz": {
               "match": "*_analyze",
               "mapping": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "analyzer": "standard_analyzer",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

with result:

```
{
   "count": {
      "type": "integer"
   },
   "is_top": {
      "type": "boolean"
   },
   "keywords_analyze": {
      "type": "text"
   },
   "count": {
      "type": "integer"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move the `strings_analz` template before the `strings` one, because the first one that matches is the one that is picked.